# Get over 32 bytes limit python smbus

Tags: python-3.x, raspberry-pi, i2c

I tried to read 50 bytes of data in arduino from a raspberry pi 3. There is this limitation that a block only have 32 bytes in length when using SMBus. Python have this library called smbus2 that provides smbus access. This library also provides a way to read beyond that 32 bytes limit using `i2c_rdwr` which I'm using. But instead of getting those 50 bytes, I'm only receiving 32 bytes and byte 33 - 49 is filled with 0xFF.

the code

```py
from smbus2 import SMBus, i2c_msg

bus = SMBus(1)
read = i2c_msg.read(addr, 50)
bus.i2c_rdwr(read)
res = list(read)

print(''.join([chr(i) for i in res]))
```

It gives:

```
[some text 32 char long]+ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ
```

Comment: Are you sure that **a)** your peripheral hardware is capable of repeated START, and **b)** your host controller is not SMBus only?

Comment: Ok my bad, there defined TWI_BUFFER_LENGTH 32 byte long, in the underlying arduino twi.c library. I can't send more than 32 byte long in 1 transmission.

Answer (score 0):

If someone stumble upon this, we can't send more than 32 byte long data in 1 transmission from arduino. We could split the data, send less than 32 byte each or loop the string and send each byte. For example:

```c
// onReceiveEvent, doesn't work
void sendMessage()
{
    Wire.write(data, LENGTH); // data length is 50 byte
                              // this however, work if LENGTH < 32
}

// onReceiveEvent, work
void sendMessage()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < LENGTH; i++)
    {
        Wire.write(data[i]);
    }
}

// reason: in file twi.c:332
/* 
 * Function twi_transmit
 * Desc     fills slave tx buffer with data
 *          must be called in slave tx event callback
 * Input    data: pointer to byte array
 *          length: number of bytes in array
 * Output   1 length too long for buffer
 *          2 not slave transmitter
 *          0 ok
 */
uint8_t twi_transmit(const uint8_t* data, uint8_t length)
{
  uint8_t i;

  // ensure data will fit into buffer
  if(TWI_BUFFER_LENGTH < (twi_txBufferLength+length)){
    return 1;
  }

  ...

  twi_txBufferLength += length;
  
  return 0;
}
```

I can still use the same python script, only the arduino is not capable of sending more than 32 byte in a single transmission.